# Register-CimIndicationEvent not working in powershell script initiated by task scheduler (at login) or gpedit.msc logon script (user configuration)?

Tags: powershell

Register-CimIndicationEvent not working in powershell script initiated by task scheduler (at login) or gpedit.msc logon script (user configuration)?

I have a script that works fine when I run it with administrative privileges from command line or PS ISE for example.  But when try to run the same script via task scheduler or even gpedit.msc user config logon script feature, it runs with no errors, but the event registration never seems to fire.  In fact, Get-EventSubscriber returns nothing?

I am running (under Task Scheduler) the same id with highest privs, the id is a local administrator on the Windows 11 system.

Is there some limitation with running Register-CimIndicationEvent at logon?  Or is there some odd context issue?  At logon the script is running in the 'current session' for the given user is it not?  Running the script with PS ISE 'run as administrator' works as expected.

Here is the script...

```
$Global:KABOOM = 255
$Global:ZERO = 0
$Global:STOP = 'ScreenSaverStop'
$Global:START = 'ScreenSaverStart'
$Global:theArgument = $args[$Global:ZERO]
$Global:theExit = $Global:ZERO
Try {
    Switch ($Global:theArgument.ToLower()) {
        'allocate' {
            $ON = {
                If (-Not(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name LIKE '%.scr'")) {
                    Add-Content -Path 'C:\Automation\Log\Event.log' -Value 'Event On Begin'
                }
            }
            If (-Not(Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query "SELECT ProcessId,ProcessName FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessName LIKE '%.scr'" -SourceIdentifier $Global:STOP -Action $ON)) {
                Throw 'No Process Stop Event Handler?'
            }
            $STANDBY = {
                If (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name LIKE '%.scr'") {
                    Add-Content -Path 'C:\Automation\Log\Event.log' -Value 'Event Off'
                }
            }

            If (-Not(Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query "SELECT ProcessId,ProcessName FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName LIKE '%.scr'" -SourceIdentifier $Global:START -Action $STANDBY)) {
                Throw 'No Process Start Event Handler?'
            }
            break
        }
        'release' {
            If (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier $Global:START -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $Global:START
            }
            If (Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier $Global:STOP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $Global:STOP
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    Write $_
    $Global:theExit = $Global:KABOOM
}
Exit $Global:theExit
```

This is to simulate the missing security event ids of 4802 and 4803 (yes we have enabled the applicable GPOs for events 4800, 4801, 4802, and 4803.  But 4802 and 4803, were removed from Windows 11 by Microsoft by error or design.  Otherwise I would use task scheduler event triggers of course.  We need to know when a screen saver is starts and stops for our internal tracking of users activity.  Also trying to avoid using an explicit polling based script to watch for process start and stop.

Is there a better why to trace powershell script execution or deeper logging to see why the script fails via gpedit login setup or task scheduler at logon setup?